# How to turn off websocket fragmentation on IIS?

Tags: iis, websocket

In my current setup I have a websocket server sitting behind IIS. Websocket requests from client are proxied to the websocket server using HttpPlatformHandler.

When I send a request bigger then 4096 bytes it is fragmented on the IIS side and received as a stream of messages on the websocket server.

Is there a way how to turn off the fragmentation on the IIS side?

Using IIS 8.5

EDIT:
receiveBufferLimit is set to maximum in system.webServer/webSocket
I am using WebSocket4Net on client side and Suave on a server side, direct connection works

Answer (score 0):

HTTPPlatformhandler does not seem to have any config [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference) for this .But for WebSocket side this may be causing the issue.

> Please make sure to **receiveBufferLimit** is set to higher value on
>   IIS side

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/websocket .

Also It seems like this can be limitation with many socket libs ,checking [this](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/issues/309) and [this](https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net/issues/2).

Comment: receiveBufferLimit is set to the Maximum value

Comment: I am using WebSocket4net on the client and it is sending the data unfragmented when connected directly to the websocket server (Suave)

Comment: Since it works directly without IIS in between, IIS definitely is doing something to the websocket request.4096 is default size of the maxURL limit of IIS configured [requestfiltering](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits) module,could you try and increase it ?

Comment: I did further research on this and it looks like IIS webSocket module itself might be fiddling with the websocket  request before it gets forwarded to HttpPlatformhandler.Since Suave can directly handle the websocket connection, Could you please also try disabling the WebSocket <webSocket enabled="false" /> ?

Comment: When I set `<webSocket enabled="false">` I receive "accept key doesn't match" exception during handshake on client.

Comment: I have not really tried this but after disabling the websocket,we may have to map the request directly to httpplatformhandler <handlers>  
      <add name="suavesocket" path="<websocketurl>" verb="*" modules="httpplatformhandler" />  
    </handlers>    Basically i am looking for a setup like [this](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/11/how-to-use-websockets-with-nodejs-apps.html) but for suave

Comment: That is basically how it is set up. I followed this tutorial [link](https://blog.vbfox.net/2016/03/31/Suave-in-IIS-hello-world.html)

Comment: Sorry i linked the wrong article.This [one](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/01/hosting-socketio-websocket-apps-in-iis.html) is what i was referring to I was asking about the urlrewrite section  <rewrite>  
     <rules>  
          <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">  
               <match url="socket.io"/>  
               <action type="Rewrite" url="server-socketio.js"/>  
          </rule>  
     </rules>  
</rewrite>